# Array of type enum coming back as string from Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Given a custom enum:
`CREATE TYPE vehicle AS ENUM ('car', 'truck', 'bicycle');`

And a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_events (
  timestamp timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
  labels vehicle[] NOT NULL,
  mentions int4[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'
);
```

When this is queried from our node application like so:

`SELECT * FROM vehicle_events;`

This returns a json structure like so:

`[{"timestamp": "January, 06 2016 23:04:56", "labels": "{'car'}", "mentions": [1,2,3,4]}]`

My question really is, why is the labels array coming back as a string(note also that the mentions array of a base type is not)? Is this because it is an array of an `ENUM`? If so, how can I force it into a regular array? And why is postgres returning it in this manner?

sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/637ce/1

Comment: `"[1,2,3,4]"` would be a string, while `[1,2,3,4]` isn't. What makes you think it is a string? Your own code shows the opposite.

Comment: the labels array is returning as a string, rather then the mentions array:
"{'car'}"

Comment: Perhaps another bug within node-postgres. Just add your own converter for the enums, via pg-types - it's quite easy.

Comment: See https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/issues/56

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is how postgres arrays look if they aren't being interpreted as arrays. If you use to_json() in the query, the array will return appropriately.

Like: `SELECT to_json(labels) as labels FROM vehicle_events;`

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is another way of doing this? Without having to explicitly cast-to-json?